# JUnit Suite produces different output when run from a build.xml

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, junit, junit4

I'm currently working on using Ant to produce html reports from JUnit test suites, but am running into some very strange problems. When I run my test suite in Eclipse, I get 30 successes, 0 errors and 0 failures. When I run the test suite as an Ant target (once again, in Eclipse) I get 7 successes, 10 errors and 13 failures, as well as different output. For the sake of this question, I'll just focus on a single test case.

Ant Target:

```
  <target name="run-unit-test" depends="build-unit-test" description="Run all unit tests.">
    <delete failonerror="false" dir="${unittest.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${unittest.dir}"/>
    <junit printsummary="true" haltonfailure="false" fork="true" forkmode="once" showoutput="true">
      <env key="BATON_HOME" value="/home/natshiel/git"/>
      <classpath>
        <path refid="libs"/>
        <path refid="junit-libs"/>      
        <pathelement location="${sep.classes.dir}"/>
        <pathelement location="${classes.dir}"/>
      </classpath>
      <formatter type="xml" usefile="true"/>
      <batchtest fork="yes" todir="${unittest.dir}">
        <fileset dir="${basedir}/build/classes">
          <!--include name="**/*Test.class"/> -->
            <include name="**/KeywordToolsTest.class"/>
          <!-- Exclude non-junit tests -->
          <exclude name="**/nbi/test/*"/>
          <exclude name="**/configmgmt/test/*"/>
          <exclude name="**/valuecollection/**"/>
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
  </target>
```

JUnit Test in Question:

```
@Test
public void testExtractKeywordsInclInvalid() {
    String fullString = "${CP_IM} ${b} ${1} ${} ${LAST-NAM[E]} ${IP}i ${12} ${34}${56} ${[BRACKETS]}";
    fullString += " hello test b ${hg ${$} ${hello word} ${12-34_ab%}";

    Set<String> validExpected = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> invalidExpected = new HashSet<String>();


    validExpected.addAll(Arrays.asList("", "1", "b", "IP", "34", "56", "LAST-NAM[E]", "12", "CP_IM", "[BRACKETS]"));
    invalidExpected.addAll(Arrays.asList("hg ${$", "hello word", "12-34_ab%"));

    Map<String,Set<String>> keywordMap = KeywordTools.extractKeywordsInclInvalid(fullString);

    Set<String> validReturned = keywordMap.get(KeywordTools.VALID);
    Set<String> invalidReturned = keywordMap.get(KeywordTools.INVALID);
    System.out.println("String: " + fullString);
    System.out.println("InclInvalid expected: " + validExpected.toString());
    System.out.println("InclInvalid returned: " + validReturned.toString());
    assertTrue(validExpected.equals(validReturned));
    assertTrue(invalidExpected.equals(invalidReturned));
}
```

Class Method Under Test:

```
public static Map<String,Set<String>> extractKeywordsInclInvalid(String input) {
    Set<String> validKW = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> invalidKW = new HashSet<String>();

    Map<String,Set<String>> results = new HashMap<String,Set<String>>();
    results.put(VALID, validKW);
    results.put(INVALID, invalidKW);

    Pattern kwAllPattern = Pattern.compile("\\$\\{(.*?)\\}");

    Matcher matcher = kwAllPattern.matcher(input);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        String kw = matcher.group(1);
        if (Pattern.matches("[\\w-_\\[\\]]*", kw) {
            validKW.add(kw);
        } else {
            invalidKW.add(kw);
        }
    }

    return results;
}
```

Output when running Test Suite in Eclipse:

```
String: ${CP_IM} ${b} ${1} ${} ${LAST-NAM[E]} ${IP}i ${12} ${34}${56}${[BRACKETS]} hello test b ${hg ${$} ${hello word} ${12-34_ab%}
InclInvalid expected: [, 1, b, 56, [BRACKETS], IP, LAST-NAM[E], 34, CP_IM, 12]
InclInvalid returned: [, 1, b, 56, [BRACKETS], IP, LAST-NAM[E], 34, 12, CP_IM]
```

Output when running Test Suite from build.xml

```
[junit] String: ${CP_IM} ${b} ${1} ${} ${LAST-NAM[E]} ${IP}i ${12} ${34}${56} ${[BRACKETS]} hello test b ${hg ${$} ${hello word} ${12-34_ab%}
[junit] InclInvalid expected: [, 1, b, 56, [BRACKETS], IP, LAST-NAM[E], 34, CP_IM, 12]
[junit] InclInvalid returned: [, 1, b, 56, IP, 34, 12, CP_IM]
```

As you can see, when running the test suite using a build.xml, the strings containing square brackets are handled incorrectly. I can't for the life of me figure out why this might be happening.

While going through the code using Eclipse's debugger, it looks like the Regex is working in a different way when being run by Ant. I have no idea how to get around this.

System Information:

CentOS 6.6

Eclipse 3.6.1

JRE 1.6.0-openjdk.x86_64

Apache Ant 1.9.6

Any ideas as to what may be going on, here? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there was a jar buried in my project that contained an old version of the class file. I added the following lines to my test class to find it:

```
Class cls = Class.forName("com.package.KeywordTools");
System.out.println("Location: " + cls.getResource("KeywordTools.class"));
```

I deleted the class file from the jar, and my problem was solved.